# Probability of getting robbed and paths enigma

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have been given an enigma and would like some help to solve it. It's night and we have to go home. We are at position A(-12,6) and would like to go to B(7,-2). Sadly, because it's night, there are some dangerous places we have to avoid like the segment IN(including I and N), the points H and G and the square JLMK. Also, unknown to us, in the square DEFC, there are some lurking thiefs and for each point(including D,E,F and C) in that zone, we have a probability S of getting robbed. What's the probability of getting robbed knowing that we can only move right or down and that we don't have any preference in the path we will take except that we will always avoid the bad spots(IN, JLMK, H and G) ?

To solve it, I first got the total number of ways to get from A to B. That's the easy part, we have 27!/(19!8!). Then I wanted to substract all the impossible paths/the paths passing through the bad spots. I drew a blank there because if I use inclusion/exclusion,it gets confusing really fast. And even if I was able to get all the possible paths, I still don't know how I'd be able to get the final probability. I had in mind that given the square DEFC, we have 0 to 6 points max of that area that we'll go through with any path. So I'd have to find the numbers of paths going through 1,2,3,4,5 and 6 points of that square, divise it by the number of possible paths to finally multiply for each case by D^n. I'd do then the sum of the result of all cases to get the desired result. But it's really long and I'm not if it's even the correct approach.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much

[We have an image here for illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAhKa.png)